# Is Apache Camel suitable for the following integration component?

Tags: java, integration, apache-camel, enterprise-integration

I'm working on a component (lets call it X) that integrates 3 services (lets call them A, B, C) with each other. It embedds a message queue. The flow looks like that:

1. Service A produces a message for the queue in X.
2. X consumes a message, based on the data in it does some computation and with the result calls service B (soap based web
   service), then based on the response data calls service C (rest
   based web service)
   2.1. Based on the data in it calls service B (SOAP WS).
   2.2. Based on the response from 2.1. it calls service C (REST WS)
3. After some computations in C, C calls back X (REST WS) and then X calls A (REST WS)

There is a chance that there will be one more service consulated on the way.

Would it be profitable to base the component X on Apache Camel? If yes, which features of Camel would be useful?

Comment: Yes Apache Camel does integration well, and has many adapters and whatnot. But your question is kinda off-topic here!

Comment: Why is it off topic? Where I should post this question?

Answer (score 0):

Apache Camel would work well here. It is also deployable in multiple containers, based on our organizations standards. The components you would need for your solution are: [camel-restlet](https://camel.apache.org/restlet.html) and [camel-cxf](https://camel.apache.org/cxf.html)

Profits: Testing is fast since you can test by running Camel in your jvm. No need of a container to run your tests.